# Java & Appium: Unable to click element

Tags: java, android, xpath, appium

In the Android app that I am testing, I am trying to click/tap the time picker. For example by default the time picker shows 08:00AM. I want to change the hour from 8 to 7 & then later on change the minutes but the xpath doesn't seem to be working. Its clicking something but the time still shows 08:00AM when I click the OK button via the code. If someone could help me then I will be able to change minutes & PM to AM as well.

Here's what I am using for tapping the hour picker so that 7 shows up selected:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[0]/android.widget.Button[0]")).click();
```

Image:

[image: Screenshot of the UI under test]

Comment: I don't have experience using Appium, but XPath index starts from `1` instead of `0`, so the first thing I'd try is changing the index of your XPath expression

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

1. Use **MobileElement**. I am using AndroidDriver also instead of RemoteWebDriver so I do not know whether that will work or not.
2. Forget click(). Use **tap(int fingers, int duration)** method of MobileElement. I have not found on the internet what duration is (seconds, milliseconds, etc so these values are just hit & trial).

I have posted the code below & it worked. It may need refinement but for now I am happy as I am not a hardcore programmer.

Now assume that hour is variable depending upon your test

```
            // change hour
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.Button");
            MobileElement hour = (MobileElement) buttons.get(0);
            List<WebElement> highlights = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText");
            MobileElement hourHighlight = (MobileElement) highlights.get(0); // highlighted hour

            // lets say we need hour = 4

            while (!hourHighlight.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if (hourHighlight.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                hour.tap(1, 10);
            }
```

Comment: method tap() is deprecated now.

Comment: @iversoncru what about `tap` in [`TouchAction`](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html) class. Isn't it valid?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find an element by Text i.e '7' and it worked for me please try with:

```
driver.findElementsByName("7").click();

or

helpers.element(By.name("7")).click();
```

You can also use variable instead of text to click on specific Time

Let me know if it works

Comment: That did not work. 7 did not appear highlighted. I had already tried it before posting here. I don't think we can use the By.Name here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElementByName("7").click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.button' and @text='7']").click();
```

Comment: Both of them did not work. The test passes but the click does not register. The time shows up as 08:00AM. Its like it did hit something but the result is not what is expected.

Comment: Thank Gaurav for taking the time but your solution did not work. I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try javascript what I found worked for Android devices when regular touches and clicks didn't register anything was this:

js.executeScript("$('# pageElement .elementClassName').trigger('touchstart')");

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the number in NumberPicker, use SendKey.

---

WebElement hour= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TimePicker[1]/android.widget.NumberPicker[0]));
    hour.sendKeys("8");