# Not able to click on the date picker button to change the date using appium and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Am not able to click on the month,date, year, hh,mm buttons on the date picker for changing the values. But using the getText method i can read the name of the buttons.

List allButtons = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.Button"));
System.out.println("previous date is "+allButtons.get(0).getText());
allButtons.get(0).click();

Java code and appium not showing any error and the testng testcase passed.
Please help
Not able to click on the date picker button to change the date using appium and java
[image]

Comment: What is the system output printing?

Comment: @NicolePhillips. This line System.out.println("previous date is "+allButtons.get(0).getText()); prints "Dec"

Comment: check out this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518284/java-appium-unable-to-click-element

Comment: can you post your appium full logs ?

Comment: @NicolePhillips Thank you. The issue is solved on using tap method. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use Swipe method to help you scroll calendar dates.

For Example :

Make a first click on your calendar icon and then use following code :

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
 for(int x=0;x<9;x++)
    {
     // Swipe syntax sould be like this way depending on your needs, you have just need to change points
     //driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);
        driver.swipe(450,550,350,500,0);  

    }
```

The loop i have used is to scroll from 1 March to 10 March for example you can change by your needs.
Tell me if that works for you.

Comment: @Emma, i dont want to use swipe method as this may fail on different devices

Comment: But it can help you i think ! Did you find another way so?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue is resolved on using tap method

Comment: Great ! happy for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"Proposed Insured Information, tab panel\"]/XCUIElementTypeTextField[3]")).click();
        
List <WebElement> values = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypePickerWheel"));
        
for (int i=0; i<values.size();i++) 
      `enter code here`{
        System.out.println(values.get(i).getText());
       }
        values.get(0).sendKeys("30");
        values.get(0).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
        
        values.get(1).sendKeys("November");
        values.get(1).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
        
        values.get(2).sendKeys("1995");
        values.get(3).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can click and select the date in devices the way you are trying. You need to use send keys. Try the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAPickerWheel[1]")).sendKeys(Dec);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAPickerWheel[2]")).sendKeys(04);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAPickerWheel[3]")).sendKeys(2015);
```

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks : This was an example, you need to change the xpath accoring to your application, also pick the datepicker wheel in android as well. and don't go for specific button as you cannot input in button.

Comment: from my experience this is not universal solution. I managed to use it for one particular Android version but after that changed the solution because was not working on latest devices.

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks : Yes this is OS specific, but in all OS cases you need to change XPath, because new OS changes the way application renders. But .sendKeys is the solution for all OS. i have tried this for different android OS till 6.0

Comment: @Keshav sendkey wont work. I have tried it. This is not a user entry field

Comment: Thanks you all. The issue is resolved in using tap method. Initially i have used AndroidDriver<WebElement> so that tap method was not available. Now i changed my driver to AndroidDriver<MobileElement>. This link was helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518284/java-appium-unable-to-click-element